# Excel adding multiple rows

Tags: excel, range, rows

IS there a quick way to do this?

For example I have two rows

A      B

34     5
56     6
34     3
25     2

I want to do the following calculation down the rows.

A1 = A1+B1
A2 = A2+B2
A3 = A3+B3
..
..

Now I can do this with a macro that loops though the rows like

```
for x = 1 to 500
sheet1.cells(x,1).vlaue = sheet1.cells(x,1).vlaue + sheet1.cells(x,2).vlaue
next x
```

but it there a more efficient way by using ranges or something where it can be carried out as a single step?

Cheers

Comment: is there a specific reason why you want to overwrite the first coloum with the result?

Comment: yes. the first collum is a current value, and the second is the step value. So each time a user clicks a button to evulate the sheet. some totals are updated and the step values are added to the "current values" to give the new "current values". Yes I could do it with three coloums, current, step, and current+step. But I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way is to enter from the immediate window:

```
[a1:a500]=[a1:a500+b1:b500]
```

The square brackets are a shortcut for the `Evaluate` function

Comment: This is about perfect for what I want. Very nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

#### Option 1

Use `Copy`, `Paste Special`, `Add`

```
Sub AddStep()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = Range([A1], [A1].End(xlDown))
    Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(, 1)
    rng2.Copy
    rng1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

#### Option 2

Loop over a variant array.  This is *much* faster than looping over a range

```
Sub AddStep()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Range([B1], [A1].End(xlDown))
    dat = rng
    For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
        dat(i, 1) = dat(i, 1) + dat(i, 2)
    Next
    rng = dat
End Sub
```

Option 1 is faster, but in some circumstances it is best to avoid the clipboard.
Tested on a sample of 1,000,000 rows:
    Option 1 - 435ms
    Option 2 - 2589ms

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is create a formula for the first row, then just select all the rows after and press `Ctrl+D`. Isn't this what you are after? Unless I misunderstood the question.

Comment: you cant do a formula in cell A1 of = A1+B1, this would be a cyclic formula where you are using the destination cell as an argument for the calculation. You have to use some VB code to keep it tidy. Trouble with using loops to loop though the rows is it is not efficient, some programming languages allow you preform calculations on arrays in a much more efficient manor.  Wondering if this can be done in excel to.